# TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined in Jquery - React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I have been using datatables.net for my react project. I created two action buttons on every row (edit, remove). Now whenever this listener run then "this" does not work. If I made jquery function to arrow function then "this.props..." works but then data is undefined.

```
$('#data-table-zero').on('click', '.edit-button', function() {
        const data = $('#data-table-zero').DataTable().row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: `/add-product`,
            state: {
                selectedRecord: { ...data }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

I hope this will help you,

```
let that = this
$('#data-table-zero').on('click', '.edit-button', function() {
        const data = $('#data-table-zero').DataTable().row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        that.props.history.push({
            pathname: `/add-product`,
            state: {
                selectedRecord: { ...data }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I know that, as i mentioned in my question that if i made that to arrow function then this.props works but then data is undefined

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check @ZainUlHassan